# Coupon code is not remove after first click of update cart button on cart page woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to apply discount on 12(quantity) and remove discount below 12(quantity).
I have created one coupon code for 20% discount('genew'). I applied and removed coupon code on when some one is clicked on update cart button on cart page(woo-commerce). Remove coupon code function is only work when someone click on update cart button two times. one first click it is not remove the coupon code.

Here are function that I am using in function.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'discount_coupon');
function discount_coupon() {
global $woocommerce;
global $count_cart_quantity;
if ( $count_cart_quantity >= 12 ) {
$coupon_code = 'genew';
if (!$woocommerce->cart->add_discount(sanitize_text_field($coupon_code))) {
    $woocommerce->show_messages();
}

}

if ( $count_cart_quantity < 12 && $count_cart_quantity > 1 ) {
$coupon_code = 'genew';
if (!$woocommerce->cart->remove_coupons(sanitize_text_field($coupon_code))) {
    $woocommerce->show_messages();
}   

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should combine these conditional statements into one, comprehensive statement:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'discount_coupon');
function discount_coupon() {
    global $woocommerce;
    global $count_cart_quantity;

    $coupon_code = 'genew';

    if ( $count_cart_quantity >= 12 ) {
        if (!$woocommerce->cart->add_discount(sanitize_text_field($coupon_code))) {
            $woocommerce->show_messages();
        }
    }
    elseif ( $count_cart_quantity < 12 && $count_cart_quantity > 1 ) {
        if (!$woocommerce->cart->remove_coupons(sanitize_text_field($coupon_code))) {
            $woocommerce->show_messages();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is that after the decreasing quantities below the 12 then it's not updating total and given the 20% discount.
if we click on first time on update button after the changing the quantities below 12 then it's not updating total price but if we click on update cart button second times then it's show me correct total.